# Show close reasons in timeline per user

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, timeline

Check this [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63448305/timeline). The question is now closed, but 3 close-votes were different.

I want to see what close reason was selected by which user directly in the timeline, therefore feature request.

P.S.: How can I see individual votes from each user? I recall someone was telling me how to do it, but I forgot. And I may forget it again .........

Comment: *I want to see what close reason was selected by which user directly in the timeline* - any particular reason why?

Comment: I don't think there is anything to gain from knowing that, and there is always potential for bickering and complaining. I

Comment: i see only that it was closed because it was too broad, where Do you see disagreement=

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [After question is closed expose close votes distinguished by reason in the timeline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/165773)

Comment: @JonClements, because I know there were 3 different votes. I was voting myself and seen others. And strange reason was auto-choosen, so I want to check again *who* votes and maybe I'll change my mind or I will make another post on meta, asking why this weird reason was chosen and not mine (obviously mine is the most correct one!). This is just one scenario.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I once tried to find all questions where I voted for a duplicate but I cannot find that information even for my close votes. The data recorded is whether there was a close vote and what closure reason the majority voted for (if the question was closed). You cannot get more granular than that - I cannot tell when I've close voted for a different reason than the majority or not. Not possible to do it for others' votes as well.

Comment: @VLAZ, I want to hear the same from devs. They should close with [meta-tag:status-declined] all opened questions. There should be one canonical question to close any following. Because search is still poor, closing as cross-site not implemented, etc. etc.. Lots of work..

Comment: @VLAZ it is currently impossible, yes. But per MSE discussions referred in my prior comment, it is doable, desirable and not too much dev effort (if memory serves major effort saver was that such change wouldn't be retroactive, ie system wouldn't rewrite timelines of previously closed questions)