# Shouldn't a post that was closed because it doesn't meet guidelines specify what guidelines?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I have occasionally happened upon a post that "doesn't meet SO guidelines," and wondered, "If I were to fix this to meet the guidelines, what guideline, specifically, was the reason why it was closed?"

This is really a case so the box that says this:

> Closed. This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers.
> Want to improve this question? Update the question so it's on-topic for Stack Overflow.
>
> Closed 3 years ago.
>
> Improve this question

... includes the specific guideline ([a list of possible reasons here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)). I do know there is a special case for "off-topic," but I don't think that should be the special case; I think *all* "guidelines not met" need to be more specific.

Comment: Isn't that what is in the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and here on meta in [meta-tag:scope]

Comment: This happens if there’s no consensus among all three close-voters. I’m not sure if the close reason is shown to users under 3k reputation.

Comment: @user4642212 From a quick test it's shown to anon users (so presumably <3k users), it's just the names of the closers that are still tucked away in the timeline.

Comment: @10Rep The close time and "Improve this question" are part of the notice provided on closed questions, as such they should stay part of the quote

Comment: @Nick I thought they were on the same line! Didn't check to see if there wasn't a new line. Is this better?

Comment: @10Rep I mean... It's meaningless, the quote was already commonmark compliant

Comment: related: [Show close reasons in timeline per user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400389/839601) and its cross-site duplicate at MSE [After question is closed expose close votes distinguished by reason in the timeline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/165773)

Comment: @user4642212 "This happens if there’s no consensus among all three close-voters." If only we would have a flexible number of close votes required that would somehow incorporate waiting for consensus (like at least two times the same close reason chosen).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, useful information *should* be shown to the OP in the close banner. In fact, it used to be the case that, when multiple close vote types were cast on a question, the banner would show each different close reason and which users voted for each reason.

A while back, however, they changed the entire close vote system (for the worse, in my opinion) and overhauled all the banners (and what information they displayed). While we *finally* hide the names of the close voters, which is good, we also now display pretty much absolutely useless messages in the close banners, leaving OPs to guess what issue(s) their question might have in the eyes of the close voters.

Comment: Ironic that the new useless messages were part of a project to make the close system more informative and friendly to newer users. Seems more confusing now