# Questions with both Close/Migrate Super User votes don't mention Super User in the close reason

Tags: bug, close-reasons

When a question is closed with two votes to migrate to Super User, and one vote to Close as "general computing hardware and software", the question is closed as "This question does not appear to be about programming" with no mention of Super User, even though all close voters selected a Super User option.

Votes 1 and 2:

[image]

Vote 3:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Here's an example: *[How do I find Skype Chat history logs in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118783/how-do-i-find-skype-chat-history-logs-in-ubuntu)*

Possibly related to *[Off-topic option: include Unix and Apple sister sites on off-topic notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380370/off-topic-option-include-unix-and-apple-sister-sites-on-off-topic-notification)*.

Comment: "[On sites which only require three votes to close questions, a unanimous vote of migration to the same site is required.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250)" for a question to be migrated. Also [Shouldn't a post that was closed because it doesn't meet guidelines specify what guidelines?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400802/11682469)

Comment: Right, but I'm saying the information about SuperUser is lost here. All three voters selected an option that mentioned SuperUser, but the closed notification doesn't mention it all all.

Comment: Where it's not unanimous - then the generic base of the majority of reasons is chosen... which ends up being "not suitable for this site"...

Comment: If 3 people voted to close as "general hardware" the close notification would say "try SuperUser", but if 3 people voted a mix of "general hardware" and "migrate to SuperUser", SuperUser doesn't get mentioned. Information is being lost here.

Comment: I think the disconnect occurring here is that the "*About general computing hardware and software*" flag reason *isn't* a migrate vote, even though the subtext makes it sound like one. That's at least mildly confusing.

Comment: The reason the close reason does not mention Super User is due to the fact it wasn't actually migrated to Super User.

Comment: You're all explaining to me how the system works. I know how the system works. I'm saying it's broken. :) I think if all close voters select close reasons that mention SuperUser, then the person who asked the question should be informed about SuperUser.

Comment: Yet all the users didn’t select the same close reason

Comment: @SecurityHound your first comment is not correct. If three people vote to close as general computing and hardware, the close reason mentions Super User, but it was not migrated to superuser.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip then what you're asking is probably a feature-request and not a bug as the current system is by-design.

Comment: @JonClements I can understand "non unanimous votes are closed with a generic reason" is by design, but I think "unanimous votes all selecting a related reason are closed without mentioning that reason" is an oversight.

Comment: So, you're saying that even though the current behavior is working as designed (and has never worked as you described -- as far as I can remember even if all close votes pointed to "About general computing..." the close reason didn't mention Super User), it's still a bug because you think it should work differently? We have different ideas of what a bug is, and I'd hate to work for the company you work for if that's what passes as a bug.

Comment: @HereticMonkey please see the 2nd image in the question. Questions closed as general computing include the text "This question is more likely to get an answer on Super User" - with a link to Super User. You can also confirm this by clicking Close on any question. I wouldn't want to comment on the accuracy of your memory but it looks like it could use a refresh, at least!

Comment: The second image in your question comes from the close dialog, not the close reason shown to the user, which is pictured in the third image in your question.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that the close reasons, when selected, mention super user, but the asker is not informed about that reason - information is lost. There is a disconnect between the information presented to the closer (Super User) and what is presented to the user (nothing). Although, I didn't realise the asker was not told about Super User even for general computing closures. That's even more confusing!