# Detailed closed reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just had my question closed with the following justification

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the
> scope defined in the help center.

Even though I disagree with that opinion, I [accept and respect that users think differently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401906/is-this-a-good-self-answered-question-or-is-there-a-better-approach?noredirect=1#comment801071_401910).

However, for more effective contributions in the community, shouldn't Stack Overflow ([as Pekka puts it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169833/362304)) consider

> a second, more detailed level of close reasons beneath
> each main reason (OT, NaRQ, Not Constructive, etc.)

Of course these ones would be different in each of the communities.

And, not only for the OP, but for the community,

> explanatory paragraphs that address why a question was closed much
> more specifically.

This last one would  be a complement to how users get their information. Pekka goes on with an example:

> **What happened to this question?**
>
> Your question was closed. 5 members of the community thought it
> is not a good fit for Stack Overflow in its current form.
>
> A closed question can no longer be answered, but it is **not deleted**. You can **edit your question**
> to improve it. If you edit your question, it will be automatically nominated for reopening.
>
> **Why was the question closed?**
>
> *(INSERT EXPLANATION OF SPECIFIC CLOSE REASON HERE)*
>
> **What can I do?**
>
> *(INSERT EXPLANATION OF SPECIFIC IMPROVEMENT POSSIBILITIES HERE)*
>
> If you feel your question was closed in error, you can flag for moderator attention or ask for support on [Meta Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401906/is-this-a-good-self-answered-question-or-is-there-a-better-approach?noredirect=1#comment801071_401910)
>
> **This is frustrating. Why aren't questions just left alone?**
>
> A closing does not necessarily mean your question is bad, and it should never be taken personally. Stack Overflow has a very narrow scope, a high standard of quality, and expects questions to be very specific. We know dealing with this can be frustrating at first - but it's worth it! We believe this strictness is part of the site's success, and makes it a more useful resource for all.

Comment: How is that reason unclear? Your question apparently isn't about programming. So think, what is it about? It's about installing Anaconda on an operating system, which isn't really on-topic here at StackOverflow

Comment: Your question was closed by three users who each used a different reason, so there is *no detailed reason to give*. Instead you got one "Other" (the comment under the post shows what they filled in for "Other"), one "About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration", and one "Needs more focus". This was probably due to you posting this on Meta and editing the post several times, presenting a different version to each close voter.

Comment: The "close" post-notice absolutely requires an improvement. It was changed not so long ago, and it's much less informative than it used to be (with worse close reasons to go along). But adding more close reasons is not the solution, it would just make it more likely users selected different options, and less likely a closing consensus emerged.

Comment: Martijn comment underlines the problem. By adding more options, a consensus would be even less likely to be reached.

Comment: @yivi in one sense it would prevent closing questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) which, in my opinion, are canonical and therefore [broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/7109869)

Comment: Your first revision was just *This QnA is meant to be an helpful user-guide on installing Anaconda on CentOS 8.*, resulting in the 'other' vote. You then added a bunch of bullet points that indeed read like a sysadmin's to do list, hence the second close vote. You then expanded the bullet points, and the last 'focus' vote was cast. It is indeed, in my view, too broad a 'question'.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. How having additional close reasons would prevent the closure of that question?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄: that's rightly closed. Stack Overflow is great for very specific types of focused questions, not something that is better covered by a good tutorial or a book.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for your feedback regarding my question. My goal was not to talk specifically about that, but addressing the Closing process.

Comment: I think Martijn refers to the question you just linked in a comment, not to "your" question. Since you referred to that question, it makes sense that other users can give their opinion about it as well, right?

Comment: @yivi regarding the closing process, for a new user and even one that is not a veteran (which is my case), I find Pekka's suggestions really helpful. Not only the detailed closed reasons (which in that case there seems to be a difference of opinions here in the comments), but also, and it is something I forgot to mention in the question, explanatory paragraphs that address why a question was closed much more specifically.

Comment: Yes, but without a clear consensus, you cannot give specific guidance. In your case, there was no consensus because the three close votes where cast for **different** reasons, as explained earlier.

Comment: @yiki the question closes by simply having the 3 close votes or a moderator needs to approve that, in fact, it is to close?

Comment: Generally, a question can be closed by three different users with more than 3k reputation voting to close. No moderator involvement required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show close reasons in timeline per user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400389/show-close-reasons-in-timeline-per-user)

Comment: @gnat more like [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/362304).

Comment: both these questions are the same, cross-site duplicates

Comment: @10 Rep: Isn't this covered by *"[What topics can I ask about here? ... software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"* (for Python in this case)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a custom close reason that provides exactly that opportunity.

However, the impetus is on new users to get to know the community they're engaging in, not veteran users attempting to teach new users, one by one, how to use the system.  The latter approach is simply not sustainable; new users outnumber veteran users by a wide margin.

At the moment, the best way for a new user to get that information is to:

1. Read the articles in the Help Center. While they don't provide a perfect introduction (and they are sequestered behind an obscure linking mechanism), they are a good start.
2. Read some questions and answers.  See which ones are well-received, and note the ones that are not.  Imagine yourself trying to answer them.  Did the OP provide enough information?  Is there context in the question: did the op "show their work" by posting some code that reproduces their specific problem?
3. Understand the Topic Area of Stack Overflow.  It's mostly "We're all about code."  Anything that's not about code, coding or algorithms is probably not on-topic.

Comment: Having said all that, I reviewed your question on Stack Overflow, and cast the last reopen vote.  Unfortunately, Stack Overflow has evolved into a pattern-based coding support system; anything that doesn't follow that specific "how do I fix my broken code" pattern is more likely to be closed, even if it otherwise seems on-topic.

Comment: If you're referring to the fact that "How to?" questions are closed unfairly, then I agree. Sometimes "How to?" questions get many views due to the way SEO works. So it's not against SO's mission.

Comment: Thank you @RobertHarvey. Never dived deeper as today in the closing process and I find Pekka's suggestion of having "explanatory paragraphs that address why a question was closed much more specifically." a plus, specially given that extra consideration of "new users outnumber veteran users". Apart from providing information, not only on those sections, it would provide clear information as the user flows in the system. And it would benefit the OP a lot.

Comment: 0. read meta posts. The help center is dry as a bone, I find that the overall interesting and more engaging nature of meta posts helps to absorb the information far easier. The first time I started to interact with the site (badly of course, like a discussion forum) I was quickly pointed to meta and spent a good 2 days reading dozens of posts. After which the general conclusion of my prior actions was "Oh. Whoops."

Comment: @Gimby: Reading meta posts is not a bad way to go, but: 1.  You have to know meta exists, and 2.  You have to know the `faq` tag exists.  Meta is rather disorganized, and I've never believed that people should have to perform extensive research on how an Internet site works before they can use it.

Comment: @Gimby I was introduced to meta through the thanks feature, and 2. It took me a **_long_** time to find out that FAQ even existed. Not only that, but after reading the site tour, I finally understood how to use this site. Meta is pretty extensive to search through.